# Is there a more efficient way to write a really long "if elif" chain in python?

Tags: python, if-statement, optimization, computer-science

I quite a beginner to real programming languages and I am using Python to write a long if elif chain to check x and y variables as coordinates and depending on the coordinates it would do something different. (This is for a text-based adventure game)

This is what I have now and I was wondering how I could do it in a much nicer way.

```
if x == 1 and y == 1:
    dothis()
elif x == 1 and y == 2:
    dothat()
elif x == 1 and y == 3:
    doANewThing()
elif x == 1 and y == 3:
    doSomethingDif()
```

Except this appears over 900 times. I hate it. Please Help.

Comment: What are the actions you're actually taking in each block? Is there a pattern to the cases that we can take advantage of, or are they completely different actions?

Comment: *this appears over 900 times* - yikes, I think that is a sign of some deeper design issues.  Why do you have so many different behaviors based on coordinates?

Comment: You could nest the subsequent elif statements under the same check for x == 1.

Comment: You may want to do some research into state machines, which is how you would typically model your game.

Comment: The different coordinates would make the in-game command "look around" give out a different response.

Comment: Could you use the coordinates as parameters for a single function?

Comment: @ThomasHuitema, That was what I was going to do but I still need a way to check WHAT the coordinates are and what that will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your short description, you probably have a different problem than you think you do =).

For example, if I was writing a program to handle the first move of a chess game, I wouldn't write out all 4096 options in the function `move(x, y, new_x, new_y)`.

Try taking a look at dictionaries or a matrix (list of list) and move towards a 'lookup -> object action' model.  For example:

```
class Thing(object):
    DESCRIPTION = 'undescribable beauty'
    def describe(self):
        return self.DESCRIPTION

class Wall(Thing):
    DESCRIPTION = 'a plain old wall'

class Townsfolk(Thing):
    DESCRIPTION = 'an angry ten-year-old'

class Nothing(Thing):
    DESCRIPTION = 'only the darkness of your soul'

map = {}  # coordinate -> thing
# TODO: load this from ascii art
map[(0, 0)] = Wall()
map[(0, 1)] = Townsfolk()
map[(0, 2)] = Wall()

def look_at(pos):
    item = map.get(pos, Nothing())
    print("You see %s" % item.describe())
```

```
>>> look_at((0,0))
You see a plain old wall
>>> look_at((0,3))
You see only the darkness of your soul
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a guess that each of the cases represents a different room in the game, and you want to call a different function for each room.

A good pattern for this is to **separate your data from the code**. Treat the coordinates and the function for each room as *data*, extract them into some sort of room list. All you need for the *code* is to check the player's coordinates, find the corresponding room function, and call it.

#### Data

A dictionary is perfect for looking up things. Let's treat the x,y coordinates as keys and the functions as values.

```
rooms = {
    (1, 1): dothis,
    (1, 2): dothat,
    (1, 3): doANewThing,
    (1, 4): doSomethingDif,
    # etc.
}
```

Notice how the function names don't have parentheses after them. It's `dothis` and `dothat`, not `dothis()` and `dothat()`. We're only listing the names of the functions here; we're not actually calling them.

#### Code

```
try:
    # Look up the function for the current room...
    room_function = rooms[(x, y)]

    # ...And call it.
    room_function()

# Error! Didn't find an entry for (x, y).
except KeyError:
    handle_error()
```

What's great about this is you can easily add new rooms to the dictionary without having to write any new if-else blocks. In fact, there *are* no if-else blocks!